# How to access checkbox value through a Controller Hook of Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm creating a controller hook of my issues_controller on Redmine. I followed [this](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Hooks) tutorial.

The question is I couldn't access the checkbox (That I created through a hook on view page) value to set my controller variable. Follow my code

_new_hook.html.erb

```
<div class="splitcontentright">
  <% @user = User.current %>
  <b><br><label for="mail_checker_issue"><%= check_box_tag "mail_checker_issue", 1, @user.pref.always_check_email %><%= l(:send_email) %></label></b>
</div>
```

issues_email_patch.rb

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  require_dependency 'issue'
  class Issue
    attr_accessor :mail_checker_issue
  end
end
```

controller_hook.rb

```
module Redmine_send_emails
  module Hooks
    class Issues_controller_hook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
      def controller_issues_new_before_save(context={})
        context[:issue].mail_checker_issue = context[:params][:mail_checker_issue]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Until where I've checked the hook works well. I've debugged the application and it called correctly the `controller_hook` method, but I couldn't find the value of my checkbox within the params.

What's wrong? How to do it?

Comment: why do you use `check_box_tag` when (I think) you should use `f.check_box` (as [here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/issues/_form.html.erb#L6)). And recheck what params come to hook: params or params[:issue]. Because if first you should retrieve value from `context[:params][:issue][:mail_checker_issue]`

Comment: f.check_box doesn't work because it's a hook and the hook can't see the form f. I got this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method f' for #<#<Class:0x67bb1f0>:0x6646d10>)`

Also I couldn't retrieve the value using `context[:params][:issue][:mail_checker_issue]`

Comment: what hook for displaying check_box do you use? For example [this hook](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/issues/_form.html.erb#L44) provides access to `form`

Comment: [this one](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/issues/new.html.erb#L3) The only hook which exists on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see your checkbox value because you display it before `labelled_form_for @issue` so it does not belongs to the form.

You can place it [here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/issues/_form.html.erb) (there are 2 place for hook)

You can try to implement gem `deface` - I managed to use it in [Redmine plugin](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_tracker_accessible/commit/86dc4e3dff106cd68dc4908861eebf76cc0cf94f).

Comment: It seems to works well as you suggested. I'm gonna do some tests here. Confirming this I come back here to accept your answer. Thanks.